# Laravel 5 authentication files duplications

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

Hi everyone I am trying to create two different signup/login forms and i want to auth both of them.Since laravel 5 come with default Auth scripts ,I am trying to duplicate the scripts for another signup and login page but I don't know whether is the good idea.Anyone who have idea on how can i approach this is welcomed. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easy to reuse Laravel's authentication logic because it has been implemented as a trait. In order to add authentication logic to a controller do one of the following in the controller:

```
//For Laravel 5.1:
class YourController {
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers; 
}

//For Laravel 5.0:
class Controller {
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers; 
}
```

This will add authentication actions to your controller - see trait's code for more details or visit http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/authentication and http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication

Comment: cool i manage to solve it but login form is giving me the problem because i have two different tables user and learner but it does not know which table to use

Comment: I see. You'll need to implement your own user provider, I'll post an example in a moment, might contain some typos as I'm writing from my head, let me know if you find any and I'll fix the answer.

Comment: ok cool check this out this is how i modify my code. here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31270025/laravel-5-how-to-work-with-authentication-on-two-different-login-forms-with-diff

Comment: I had a look at Laravel code and having separate sets of users in 2 tables would require quite a lot of work: write your own user provider and laravel authentication Guard class. It's doable, but it might break other vendors packages that use Laravel's Auth facade, and that is quite popular - all packages that use Auth class might break because the new interface would need to be different as passing a model name (learner or user) would be required.for all Auth methods.

Comment: Easier option is to store users in one table but use some column (e.g. type) to differentiate between users and learners. If you then want to log in only learners in one controller and only users in the other it would require very little coding. let me know if this is ok for you and I'll create a code snippet

Comment: The reason i think i need two tables is because after registering the user the user must start registering the learners after of which is tricky.I u have any other methods and thoughts about how can i do this please let me know.

Comment: Since the method that i am trying to implement is very tricky is there a way that i can handle the scenario i've explained on my previous comment?

Comment: because the login strategy is not the same the users use email and learners use cell number

Comment: It's very easy to do even if you have users in one table with additional type column.

Comment: I'll post example in the other question