# Laravel 5 How to work with authentication on two different login forms with different tables

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I created two different login forms with two different register forms and two different tables ,at the moment i can do the following

```
Login into table A(users)
Register into table A(users)
Register into table B(students)
```

But i can't logon on table B ,is like it is getting confused on which table to logon .I just modified the auth built-in functionality

Here is my code function for login under

```
     public function postLoginl(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'learnerCell'=> 'required', 'password' => 'required',
    ]);

    $credentials = $this->getCredentialsl($request);

    if (Auth::attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember'))) {
        return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
    }

    return redirect($this->loginPath())
        ->withInput($request->only('learnerCell', 'remember'))
        ->withErrors([
            'learnerCell' => $this->getFailedLoginMessage(),
        ]);
}
```

When I check on config/auth.php there is a script

```
 <?php

  return [
     'driver' => 'eloquent',
      'model' => App\User::class,
      'table' => 'users',
           'password' => [
    'email' => 'emails.password',
    'table' => 'password_resets',
    'expire' => 60,
  ],

];
```

of which i think is where the problem lies,because it does not have model to control the login it only references one model (User) and I have another one called (Learner).

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using **Laravel 5.1** - let me know if it's not true and I'll try to help you with other version as well.

Easiest way to do this is to store users in a single table with additional **type** flag. I understand that you want to have 2 different login processes and different credentials to be used for login. Once you have users in the same table the way to do that is:

```
class UserController {
    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    //use email for authentication
    public $username = 'email';

    protected function getCredentials(Request $request)
    {
        //allow only users with type=user
        return array_merge($request->only('email', 'password'), ['type' => 'user']);
    }
}

class LearnerController {
    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    //use phone for authentication
    public $username = 'phone';

    protected function getCredentials(Request $request)
    {
        //allow only users with type=learner
        return array_merge($request->only('phone', 'password'), ['type' => 'learner']);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I am on 5.1 ,but lt came with most of the functions of which under AuthenticatesUsers.php there is some getCredential function so how is it going to work now and again the "type" i wish i can share my project with u to see what i mean

Comment: getCredentials is the function that AuthenticatesUsers trait uses to fetch user from the database. So if the function returns ['email'=>'email@email.com', 'password'=>'xyz', 'type'=>'user'] then the trait will load user of type "user" and email equal to "email@email.com" and then will validate provided password against user password hash stored in the database.

Comment: I am lost now ,can i share my project with u just to see what i did ,if possible?

Comment: Sure, just give me the link

Answer (score 0):

It can be done as below,

Under `app\Http\Controllers\Student` create `AuthCotroller` as below. This controller will handle student authentication.

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers\Student;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController as MainAuthController;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AuthController extends MainAuthController {

    public $loginPath = '/student/login';

    public $redirectPath = '/student/dashboard';

    public $redirectAfterLogout = '/student/login';

    /**
     * Show the application login form.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function getLogin()
    {
        return view('student.login');
    }

    /**
     * Log the user out of the application.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function getLogout()
    {
        $this->auth->logout();

        return redirect(property_exists($this, 'redirectAfterLogout') ? $this->redirectAfterLogout : '/');
    }

    /** This method overrides Trait method. So, We can redirect Different Users to different destinations
     * Get the post register / login redirect path.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function redirectPath()
    {
        if (property_exists($this, 'redirectPath'))
        {
            return $this->redirectPath;
        }
        return property_exists($this, 'redirectTo') ? $this->redirectTo : '/student/dashboard';
    }
}
```

Now create following middleware,

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class ChangeUserToStudent
{

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param  \Closure $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        \Config::set('auth.table', 'students');
        \Config::set('auth.model', 'App\DB\Student');

        \Config::set('session.cookie', 'student_session');
        \Config::set('session.path', '/student/');

        return $next($request);
    }

}
```

Now in `app/Http/kernel.php` register above middleware with other middleware as below,

```
/**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
          .....
    'user.student' => 'App\Http\Middleware\ChangeUserToStudent',
          .....
        ];
```

now in `routes.php` create following routes group with middleware `user.student`,

```
<?php
// Protected Routes by auth and acl middleware
Route::group(['prefix' => 'student', 'namespace' => 'Student', 'middleware' => ['user.student']], function () {
    Route::get('login', [
        'as' => 'student.login',
        'uses' => 'AuthController@getLogin'
    ]);
    Route::get('logout', [
        'as' => 'student.logout',
        'uses' => 'AuthController@getLogout'
    ]);
    Route::post('login', 'AuthController@postLogin');
});
//Other student routes accessed only after login
Route::group(['prefix' => 'student', 'namespace' => 'Student', 'middleware' => ['user.student','auth']], function () {

    Route::get('dashboard', [
        'as'         => 'student.dashboard',
        'uses'       => 'DashboardController@index'
    ]);
]);
```

I hope you have already created `Student` model and `students` table which should essentially be at least same as a `users` table.
Now, while you access route with `student` prefix, `user.student` middleware will jumps in and changes the authentication table to `students` and model to `Student` on the fly. You can even have different session for `student` as I have already shown.

Under `view` directory you can put all student related views under `student` directory. I assume you have separate login form for student
which you should create under `view\student` directory.

This way you can completely separate `student` section from `users` section. 
I hope it helps.

Comment: i am trying to follow ur code but i have know luck would u also like to view my code ? i've been doing this for 2 days i dont wat i am doing wrong

Comment: i getting TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 53: when trying to logon user student now

Comment: Can you clear browser cache or try it from different browser? If that does not work, try commenting out session.cookie and session.path from middleware.

Comment: @pinkalvansia I try this solution but I keep redirected to /auth/login instead of /panel/login (in my case)