# How to have two authentications in a Laravel 5 application?

Tags: php, laravel, basic-authentication, laravel-5.1

I am developing a Laravel 5.1 application with Oauth authentication with Google using Socialite. All relevant code went into the AuthController.php and that part went smooth. Now I want to have a set of admin role users who will log in using their `username` and `password` using a login form. The username and passwords for these users will be stored in a different table `admin_users`. How do I proceed with this?

- I have created a model `AdminUser`
- Should I duplicate the auth.php in config with the model set to my new AdminUser class?
- Should I continue using the AuthController?

Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at the updated version of Ollie Read's [multiauth](https://github.com/sboo/multiauth) package. Another approach I've used in the past is to use Laravels auth for front end users, and another package like Sentry for backend users.

Comment: Sentry seems to have support for Laravel 4. Does it work with Laravel 5 as well ?

Comment: I think they renamed the project to sentinel which seems to support 5.

Comment: look at this if it can help you?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31270025/laravel-5-how-to-work-with-authentication-on-two-different-login-forms-with-diff/31275286#31275286